# Email Confirmation - Invalid Token

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

In my .Net Core 3.1 project, sometimes tokens are invalid as error says.

According to this thread : [ASP.NET Core Identity invalid token on confirmation email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781295/asp-net-core-identity-invalid-token-on-confirmation-email/58581494#58581494)

I am following the instructions so I have changed my `SendConfirmationLink` action as below:

```
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
byte[] tokenGeneratedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code);
var codeEncoded = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(tokenGeneratedBytes);

var callbackURLRoute = Url.Action("RegisterStandartUser", "Account", new
                       {
                           userId = user.Id,
                           token = codeEncoded
                       });

var callbackURL = $"{HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{HttpContext.Request.Host}{callbackURLRoute}";

await _mailService.SendConfirmationMailToStandartUser(user, callbackURL);
```

After this mail successfully delivers to users, some of the users can confirm their account but some of them are getting this error message.

The error is `Invalid Token` on server side.

My `RegisterUser` action (the link redirects to) is below:

```
 var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
 if (user == null) { throw new Exception("Cannot find user!"); }

var codeDecodedBytes = WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(model.EmailToken);
var codeDecoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(codeDecodedBytes);

var emailConfirm = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, codeDecoded);
```

Why my application sometimes accepts and sometimes doesn't those tokens?

Please help me...

Comment: The problem might be that the token is timing out because the users are waiting too long to respond. I believe the default timeout on the token is 30 minutes.

Comment: Very enlightening answer! I am gonna try this and I will share the results with you.

Comment: My comment was from experience. This happened to me when using the default password reset facilities provided in IdentityServer4, which is built around Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity .

Answer (score 0):

you have to create link like this :

```
var confirmationLink = Url.Action("EmailConfirmation", "Account", new { email = user.Email, token = token }, Request.Scheme);
```