# Email Confirm in MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to send a confirmation email from my API. The mail is sent without problems.

When I load the url from MVC5, I have this error:

[image]

I tried:

[Asp.NET Identity 2 giving "Invalid Token" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405307/asp-net-identity-2-giving-invalid-token-error)

http://www.gunaatita.com/Blog/Invalid-Token-Error-on-Email-Confirmation-in-Aspnet-Identity/1056 --> My api and my MVC are two projects hosted on two servers, for this reason I try using machineKey validationKey.

The code I use is below:

**Web API**

```
        if (!await db.Users.AnyAsync(c => c.Email == userRequest.Email)) return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(userContext));
        userManager.UserTokenProvider = new TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, string>();

        var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userRequest.Email);

        var userId = user.Id;
        var code = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

        var url = "MyUrl" + "/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=" + userId + "&code=" + code;
```

**MVC5**

```
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }

        var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
        return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
```

Comment: What was the value of `code` when it didn't work?

Comment: API and mvc pointing to the same data source for user management?

Comment: @mjwills like this userId=e6710368-9dd2-4417-9096-68642b80314f&code=843473

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, yes both point to the same database

Comment: Do you get the expected code and userId in mvc?

Comment: @AmanB yes, it's the same :|

Answer (score 0):

For the token confirmation to work, the **token needs to be saved** in the Users table `AspNetUsers`.

**Web API**

```
string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
user.ConfirmationToken = code;
UserManager.Update(user);
```

**MVC5**

```
var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);         
switch (result.Succeeded)
{
    case true:
    // Your code
    case false:
    //
    default:
    //
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it throws 'invalid token' because the code parameter is too complex for querystring (contains special characters). So it is not redirecting to the page properly. To solve this problem:

```
string val = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(code));
```

You can change to 'code' parameter with this.

Comment: I try copy your code and paste ... and I have the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure but about this solution but did you try to set machine key of websites? Is the machine key on all servers the same? You can set them with web.config or IIS