# How to set custom token provider for cookies in ASP.NET Core Identity 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity

tl;dr: Is there way how to set custom `TokenProvider` or something similar e.g. (jwt tokens has `IssuerSigningKey`) to cookies?

I have a .Net Core 3.1 backend with identity Authentication. I had a problem with confirming generated email token.. “Invalid Token” error. From this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56355282/13022807) I found out there can be problem with my hosting. I have shared hosting for my application and my application was often restarted. I believe this was causing my problems. So as answer suggested I created my own `TokenProvider`:

```
   services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>()
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
           .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
           .AddTokenProvider<AesDataProtectorTokenProvider<AppUser>>(TokenOptions.DefaultProvider);
```

This helps. For authentication I was using JwtBearer tokens with custom IssuerSigningKey

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        })
```

I found out that `SignInManager` from `Identity` is creating Cookies by default. So I tough it will be better to use this cookies instead of my jwt tokens saved in `localstorage`. So I set up expiration time for my cookies to 30 days.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
});
```

Everything worked great.. until I hosted my application to server. I believe that when my app is restarted, cookie validation fail and I am getting 401 from server. So..finally to my question.. Is there way how to set custom `TokenProvider` or something similar e.g. (jwt tokens has `IssuerSigningKey`) to cookies?

Answer (score 0):

There are no existing API (class, method) for you customize cookies in ASP.NET Core Identity.

You can build yourself without ASP.NET Core Identity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/CookieBuilder.cs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookiebuilder?view=aspnetcore-3.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions?view=aspnetcore-3.0