# "Invalid token." during Verifying ResetPassport and ConfirmEmail Methods of UserManager in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, token

I made the method to get a reset token and reset the passport in a single route it works fine for the single route as below:

```c#
[HttpGet("ResetPassword")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword(string userId)
        {
          var Password = "Random@123";
          var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
          var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
          var resetStatus = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, Password);
        }
```

But if I separate the GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync and ResetPasswordAsync into different routes I get an error of invalid token I try dowing URL encoding and all other solutions available but it didn't work I also implemented a custom token handler as suggested by [Custom Token Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405307/asp-net-identity-2-giving-invalid-token-error). But getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
It is caused by the database. I made configured it with a new database and with a new migration script and it is working now.