# UserManager: GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync() and ConfirmEmailAsync() in different web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

I have 2 ASP MVC Core web applications (referencing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App, Version 2.1.1`). Both running locally in Visual Studio on my machine.

1. If I call inside 1st web application

```cs
    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
```

2. and then on the 2nd web application

```cs
    var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
```

I got the result `"Invalid token."`.

---

I've read [ASP.NET Core 2.0 - ASP.NET Identity - Invalid Token Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283074/asp-net-core-2-0-asp-net-identity-invalid-token-error) but my issue is different. It doesn't work locally, too!

(I guess setting the `machineKey` wouldn't help because both applications are running on my local machine. And even if I have no `web.config` locally.)

Comment: are they connectin to the same server? do they have the same id?

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, as I wrote both "are running on my local machine".

Comment: i mean the db??

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, both are using the same DbContext class and the same connection string (`mssqllocaldb`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token is persisted to the database, so all you need is to be able to properly decrypt it on the other side. For that, if both your apps are ASP.NET Core, then you need only setup the data protection providers for both apps to connect to the same external store and use the same application name. The external store could be a network location, mapped drive, Azure Key Vault, etc. You should review the [full documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2), but essentially:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName("shared app name")
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\share\directory\"));
```

You may or may not need to assign one app as a primary key ring manager. By default, each app will rotate keys automatically, which could potentially be an issue if you have multiple apps sharing the same keys. You can disable key rotation on a per app basis via:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration();
```

Essentially, you'd add this to all subordinate apps, leaving only the one you designate as the primary to rotate keys.

Comment: `services.AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName("shared app name");` did the trick. Thanks alot!